# Is it possible to know the value of color temperature that camera applied on JPEG Images at taken moment?

Tags: white-balance

I want to develop an app for smartphones to measure some special parameters with taking images. I think if I have the color temperature value that camera in auto white balance mode applied on that image, I can estimate that parameter more accurately. Do you think is there any way to find this value?
I know that is possible in raw files, but i want to know can I find in somewhere in jpg image captured by smartphone or can I calculate it?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is really about the APIs that smartphones make available. That's not a photography question -- it's a programming one, and one that's specific to each phone OS.

Comment: I'd say that "can I find it in the JPEG?" makes this on-topic.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I can't see why. It's still about "measuring some special parameters", not about photography. (Cameras can also be used as doorstops or to pound in nails, but those questions are also off topic.)

Comment: I asked this question in programming section but they told me it depends to photography and you should ask it in there. Now you asking me to ask this question in programming one. What should I do ?!!!

Answer (score 1):

Check the metadata with exiftool. If it is there, you are lucky. I don't think color space information of this detail is captured, especially with a smartphone..

Comment: exiftool doesn't show the color temperature value of raw file ! I found it in adobe Photoshop for raw file. but there was nothing for jpg file. Even the jpg file that was captured by a DSLR camera !!

Comment: If the jpeg image has color temperature information, you can retrieve it with this exiftool command:  exiftool -ColorTemperature <file name>. I just tested it and it works on jpg files I have.

Comment: Clarification to the above - random test shows that my digital camera files have this exif information, but mobile phone files don't.

Comment: I test with my camera (Sony Nex 3N) But I couldn't find it in JPEG mode. What is the brand of your Camera?